# python-Pandas df.sum() across multiple columns unexpected arg 'axis' error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

here I have a pandas Dataframe df like:

```
     A    B    C
 0   1    2    3
 1   1    2    3
 3   1    2    3
```

Then I have a list

```
x=['B','C']
```

I want to get the sum of each number of each row under B & C columns. So I write like:

```
df[x].sum(axis=1).values
```

However, I get an error

```
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I don't understand why this will give an error. My code is run in ipython notebook. Could you give any suggestions? Thanks.

UPDATE: the real df is like:

```
                  Date      Ayotte  Hassan
Date                                 
2016-06-29     2016-06-29    46.8    45.3
2016-06-30     2016-06-30    46.8    45.3
2016-07-01     2016-07-01    46.8    45.3
2016-07-02     2016-07-02    46.8    45.3
2016-07-03     2016-07-03    46.8    45.3
2016-07-04     2016-07-04    46.8    45.3
2016-07-20     2016-07-20    45.8    45.2
2016-07-21     2016-07-21    45.8    45.2
2016-07-22     2016-07-22    45.8    45.2
   ...            ...         ...     ...
2016-10-09     2016-10-09    48.0    44.5
2016-10-10     2016-10-10    48.0    44.5
2016-10-11     2016-10-11    46.7    44.7
2016-10-16     2016-10-16    46.3    44.0
2016-10-17     2016-10-17    46.3    44.0
2016-10-18     2016-10-18    46.0    44.3
2016-10-19     2016-10-19    45.7    45.3
2016-10-20     2016-10-20    44.0    46.0
2016-10-21     2016-10-21    44.0    46.0
2016-10-22     2016-10-22    44.0    46.0
2016-10-23     2016-10-23    44.0    46.0
```

The dtypes of df is

```
Date      datetime64[ns]
Ayotte           float64
Hassan           float64
dtype: object
```

Then, I did

```
df = df.resample('D')
```

The df shown above is the data before resample. The list x is

```
x=['Ayotte','Hassan']
```

Then the error comes when I run this code

```
print df[x].sum(axis=1).values
```

Comment: Did you mean to have your index go 0, 1, 3 in your DataFrame?  Because I did the exact same thing (with the proper indicies) and it works.

Comment: @pshep123 that won't matter

Comment: `.values` is the issue

Edit, I take that back....It works either way for me

Comment: @pshep123 My df's index is the date like 2016-11-18.

Comment: @anshanno I tried without `.values`, but still get the same error.

Comment: @Mr_Pi post your data set

Comment: @Mr_Pi also make sure you are using Pandas sum function.  I am starting to think you are probably using Python's...I don't use ipython notebook so I don't know if that would even be possible though

Comment: @anshanno I think I am using Pandas sum function. Because the `.sum()` follows the `df[x]`, which is a Dataframe.

Comment: @Mr_Pi Very strange...

Comment: @anshanno The original df is updated, please have a look.

Comment: so you want to add Ayotte  Hassan?

Comment: @anshanno yes. I want to add the values of these two columns. Sorry to forget to give the list x.

Comment: @Mr_Pi posted answer below.  Let me know if that is the result you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose w/o a continuous example that demonstrate the error.

If I start out with:

```
import numpy
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3),
    index=['a', 'b', 'c'],
    columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z']
)
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
   X  Y  Z
a  0  1  2
b  3  4  5
c  6  7  8
```

I can then do:

```
df[['X', 'Y']].sum(axis=1)
```

To get:

```
a     1
b     7
c    13
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also try something myself and there is no error. My actual dataframe df has three columns: date, person1, person2. The index of df is also date. The date is like 2016-11-18. Under person1/2, there are float64 numbers. when I try to calculate the sum as above, then I will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
,Date,Ayotte,Hassan
2016-06-29,2016-06-29,46.8,45.3
2016-06-30,2016-06-30,46.8,45.3
2016-07-01,2016-07-01,46.8,45.3
2016-07-02,2016-07-02,46.8,45.3
2016-07-03,2016-07-03,46.8,45.3
2016-07-04,2016-07-04,46.8,45.3
2016-07-20,2016-07-20,45.8,45.2
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', index_col=0)
df['Total'] = df[['Ayotte', 'Hassan']].sum(axis=1)

print df
```

Out:

```
                  Date  Ayotte  Hassan  Total
2016-06-29  2016-06-29    46.8    45.3   92.1
2016-06-30  2016-06-30    46.8    45.3   92.1
2016-07-01  2016-07-01    46.8    45.3   92.1
2016-07-02  2016-07-02    46.8    45.3   92.1
2016-07-03  2016-07-03    46.8    45.3   92.1
2016-07-04  2016-07-04    46.8    45.3   92.1
2016-07-20  2016-07-20    45.8    45.2   91.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but still get the same error. However, I found if I remove the line `df = df.resample('D')`, then it will work. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Mr_Pi not sure exactly, I have never used resample.  Are you using that resample just to get the date into Year-Month-Day?  From the docs it looks like you are supposed to call it on a per series basis `series.resample()`.  But if all you want is the date in Y-m-d you should be using something like `df['in_day'] = df.my_datetime.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: `resample` doesn't return a dataframe. it returns a grouping object, you need to aggregate the `resample` object before treating it like a normal dataframe.